# Best way query a database for nearby lat/longs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, database

I have a set or lat/longs stored in a db. I want to query the db and return documents that are within range of another lat/long. I know how to determine the distance between two sets but I don't want to have to do that for every entry in the db. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [Geospatial Indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) to achieve this...

If that's no good, I actually built a node.js addon to perform nearest neighbor searches called [node-kdtree](https://github.com/justinethier/node-kdtree). It could be used to find the closest n points, and is fairly quick since it is just a wrapper to an underlying C library. But it sounds like it would be a poor choice for your needs because you would have to pull all of your data out of the DB first in order to process it. With the limited information I have, I suggest that you try using the built-in functionality of mongodb first.